# Design and optimization of a Sun-synchronous repeating ground track orbit constellation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, mission-design, sun-synchronous

I am currently researching about this topic and am very new to this.

Have no clue how to go about designing a group of imaging satellites (constellation) that are sun synchronous with repeating ground tracks in low earth orbit (figuring the number of satellites, planes, etc.) that:

1-maximizes regional coverage (for example be able to continuously cover at least 70% of a target location e.g. country)

2-minimizes number of planes to reduce launch costs (optimization step)

I don't have access to STK so I need to figure out the right orbital mechanics equations and then code them in MATLAB. As of now I only have generated the altitudes and inclinations combinations for sun synchronous low earth orbits. So I can use these combinations as inputs for getting other constellation parameters like number of satellites, planes, etc. and then choose the right combination that generates maximum coverage of the region (1) and further optimize it (2). I have read many papers but they are mostly confusing to me because I don't have the background, so I would really appreciate any advice and assistance. I have been stuck on this for quite a while.

Comment: May i suggest you include the more verbose form of your acronyms, at least for first usage thereof? I *think* that by "RGT constellation" you mean a group of satellites with "repeating ground track", in which can maybe look to things like https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1270963814002351

Comment: thanks for the comment, but im looking for constellation design not just a single satellite.